# How to fix en error when running an SQL Script in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-module

I made an SQL Script (I checked it for errors and everything was fine). After that, I opened it in MySQL Workbench. I wanted to run it to view my query results. I clicked: File - Run SQL Script. I selected my file and it came up with an error:

```
error calling Python module function SQLIDEUtils.runSQLScript
```

What should I do to successfully run my script file?

Answer (score 2):

In the MySQLWorkbench, instead of File > Run SQL Script, could you try to use File > Open SQL Script followed by Query > Execute (All or Selection)? This way, you should see an output from each query of the schema.sql script.

You could also try to use the mysql command (from a command line) instead. Or, splitting the schema.sql into smaller chunks to isolate the problem.

If nothing work I suggest you check the MySQL Workbench installation.

Comment: I tried to do like you said, but the option Execute (All or Selection) is grey and I'm not able to click it.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

i think you are not logged in mysql server 
solution

1. after downloading mysql workbench and mysql server

2.when you are open mysql workbench left-downside see there mysql connections click on that

3.enter username and password

4.query Execute-all will start working

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, turns out I was simply not connected to the Local instance of MySQL. All I had to do was `open MySQL Workbench > Toolbar > Database > Connect to Database > Stored Connection (choose local instance mysql) > ok`. If it asks for root password, it's just your windows user password.

Comment: Seems the option you are suggesting "choose local instance mysql" doesn't exist. As a check, i though it might involve with Python, and checked in command prompt for Python installation, and it does exists! So what might be the problem here?